# Jquery Traversing to the Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

take a time To look at this website http://www.thejewelrysource.net/ and stay for like 7 seconds in the bottom left corner there is a small pop up that will appear and disappear again I want to do something like that **using Jquery**.

[image: pop up]

I know I could use Slideup and SlideDown Method but **the problem I am facing is that How could traverse to the Given data in an Array so that I will Pop up the Data One at a Time.** I am using only Static Data. Thank you for your Help in Advance! may someone help me! Thank You So Much

Comment: What difference does static data make? Do you want it to pick an element from the "_Given data in an Array_" and display just that one element, loop through the items? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44193215/edit) your post to include what you have tried so far...

Comment: No code... No help. That's life.

Comment: I'm afraid your question is using such poor English that it's possible no one will understand you. I certainly don't know what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't understand much from your description. By any chance is this what are you looking are?

I have used `setTimeout` and `setInterval` to simulate this and a closure variable to keep track of the next item to display.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var $popup = $(".popup"),
    aMessages = ["Hello", "This is alert", "Is this what are you look for?"],
    counter = 0;

  $(".popup").hide();

  var interval = setInterval(showMessage, 3000);

  function showMessage() {
    var iMessageId = counter % aMessages.length;
    $popup.text(aMessages[iMessageId]);
    $popup.show();
    counter++
    setTimeout(hideMessage, 1000);
  }

  function hideMessage() {
    $(".popup").fadeOut(100);
  }
  
  setTimeout(function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }, 10000);
});
```

```css
.popup {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="popup"></div>
```

Comment: Wow you actually attempted to answer that question, you're more adventurous than I! :P

Comment: Haha, yes.. This is what I do when I am super bored! :P